How can I specify an arrow from a distant bond to another bond in Chemfig?
I have an issue regarding regarding using Chemfig to display an electron movement arrow from a distant bond to another. I have tried every possible arrangement of arguments but not found a solution. I am trying to display the Grignard-Mechanism (This is the reference image)
and for the hexagonal intermediate state I have figured out this much
\setchemfig{debug=true}
\schemestart
\chemleft[
\chemfig{O(-[@{a2}::30,,,,dash bond]@{d1}Mg?[a](-[::60]Br))=[@{a1}::270](<[::-40]*6(=-=-=-))(<:[::-80](*6(=-=-=-)))(-[@{b2}::60,,,,dash bond]([::-60]*6((-[@{b1}::120,,,,dash bond]Mg(-[@{d2}::60,,,,dash bond]([::-60]*6(=?[a,,,,dash bond]-=-=-)))(-[::-60]Br))=-=-=-)))}
\chemright]
\arrow{->[\footnotesize\text{- }\chemfig{C_6H_5-MgBr}]}[,2]
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw(a1).. controls +(45:5mm) and +(-90:5mm).. (a2);}
\chemmove{\draw(b1).. controls +(90:3mm) and +(60:3mm).. (b2);}
\chemmove{\draw(d1).. controls +(-90:3mm) and +(180:7mm).. (d2);}

But I am not able to attach the arrow to the distant bond(drawn using ?[a]) between Magnesium on the top and the benzol ring. Where should I insert the @{d1} parameter? Am I missing something else?
I have tried rearranging the @{d1} parameter without any success. It should belong into the [a,,,,dash bond] bracket, but this just throws a syntax error when putting anywhere within the commas.
